# How can I decrease the render time of this view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It takes a long time for my view to render. It consists of a table populated from about 90 table records. The dB calls are running very quickly, but it takes a while to display all the records. Here is the bit of code causing the sluggishness:

```
<table>               
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PositionEdits.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PositionEdits[i].PositionID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PositionEdits[i].PositionID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PositionEdits[i].PositionDescr)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PositionEdits[i].Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @*editable*@
                @Html.DropDownList("Position",
                    new SelectList(Model.Positions),
                    Model.PositionEdits[i].Position)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OldPositions[i].Position)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PositionEdits[i].Position)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I realize that paginating would solve my problem, but I was hoping to show all ~90 records on the same page. Is there a way I can improve this view to decrease load time?

Comment: Just make it asynchronous. Page will load first and table will "appear" when finished (but 90 or more comboboxes may slow down your browser...)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: That's not even remotely correct. Async doesn't return a response quicker. It just releases the thread back to the app pool to field other requests until the action is ready for it again. The time to page-load is the same sync vs async. In fact, since async adds overhead, it might actually end up being a tad bit slower.

Comment: You could cache the 90 results for a period of time (assuming they do not have to be real time) and serve from cache?

Comment: Is that model an EF entity or maybe an NHibernate entity? What are the templates like for the DisplayFor calls?

Comment: @ChadRuppert its an EF entity

Comment: @navig8tr and is the position collection lazy loaded?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I was getting more at the fact was that if he's passing an EF model directly to the view, and that collection is lazy loading or has further objects in the graph, he might be hitting select N+1 issue during view rendering.

Comment: @ChrisPratt sorry if I've not been clear. I do not mean to make that method async, do it in a Task or something like that (pretty meaningless in this context). I mean to make an AJAX asynchronous request for that HTML table (then client side with JavaScript). Total time won't decrease (it'll even increase) but user will have perception of faster page load (BTW yes a table with 90 rows made by many controls may render slowly on some browsers).

Comment: @ChadRuppert sorry, message was for Chris! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, if you're still in local development, especially if you're using debug in Visual Studio, it is the absolute wrong time to worry about things like page load times. You're dealing with a very light-weight single-headed server with tons of overhead caused by the integration back and forth with Visual Studio and its tooling. Page load times are meaningless.

Once you've got something workable, you can deploy it to a production-ready server environment to test performance. Unless you're running on full blown IIS on a dedicated web server with the actual RAM and other resources you plan to devote to the site in production, any measurement of performance is meaningless as it's out of context.

If it's still slow, which I don't see any way it possibly could be (90 records on an actual web server with full IIS with even a modest amount of system resources is trivial), you'll need to investigate what part is really slowing you down. There's time involved in the initial transmission of the request, database queries, the actual server time generating a response, time to send that response back to the user, time it takes for the browser to render the HTML and CSS, issue requests/receive responses for additional resources like CSS, JS files and images, and time to execute any JS on the page.

Using the developer tools of your browser (Chrome has a particular good set in this regard), you should be able to see a gantt chart indicating when each request was issued and how long it took to get the response. That only tells part of the story though. You'll need additional tools to dig deeper once you find some problem areas to look at. I personally use [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). This will give you very detailed information about how long just about every part of the process took and what pieces of your application are slowing you down. The steps you need to take to fix the problem will largely depend on what is actually causing the problem, which so far is still a mystery.

Comment: I disagree, particularly if you are using an ORM tool that supports lazy loading. This would be the perfect time to check on that sort of thing. EF Profiler is a great tool to run during development time. The issue he is reporting could EASILY be a lazy loading issue, and not a rendering issue at all.

Comment: Query profiling is an entirely different situation than straight up performance testing.  It's somewhat related,  but profiling queries may not even focus on speed but efficiency. Sometimes slower is better if it doesn't slam your database under load. The OP here is generically discussing page load time and that is premature at this stage in the application life cycle.

Comment: While this is true, however, things like the lazy loading as I discussed can often disguise themselves as poor page load times. That is all I intended.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will definitely look into your suggestions and try both Glimpse and EF Profiler. As you say, Chris, it's probably too soon to begin any kind of optimization, but I would like to know if the issue is being caused during rendering. I timed the dB calls using the Stopwatch class and they seemed to be very fast. Also, I removed the contents from the table (except some dummy data) and added the contents one one value at a time. In doing this it seemed the dropdown box gave the biggest hit in terms of load time. However, I'm still not sure why there is such a big hit.

Comment: Also, the page actually seems to load quickly (everything is visible), but the page is unresponsive.

Comment: I would look at any JS you have running on page then.

Comment: @ChadRuppert: The collection isn't lazy loaded. Three lists are created in the controller (`PositionEdits`, `Positions`, and `OldPositions`) and this appears to take very little time (checked with Stopwatch class). Then the lists are accessed from the view via the code shown in the OP.

Comment: @Chris Pratt: I disabled all JS and there seems to be no effect. At this point I think I'll go with your original suggestion and put the app on the sever and test it there.